# $_GET method give wrong value

Tags: php

**firstPage.php**

```
 <?php
                $linkName="Second Page";
                $id=5;?>
                <?php $company="Zubair";
                ?>

                <a href="secondPage.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&company<?php echo $company;?> "> 

                <?php echo $linkName; ?>
                </a>
```

**SecondPage.php**

```
            <?php 
            $company = $_GET['company'];
            //echo $company;
            ?>
```

when i click on firstPage link get this error **Undefined index company**. and variable Company join with CompanyName

```
(
    [id] => 5

    [companyZubair] => 
)
```

> Notice:  Undefined index: company in C:\xampp\htdocs\HayDay\secondPage.php on line 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing `=` after `company`, this should work fine.

```
 <?php
        $linkName="Second Page";
        $id=5;?>
        <?php $company="Zubair";
    ?>

<a href="secondPage.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&company=<?php echo $company;?>"><?php echo $linkName;?></a>
```